# I am loosing standard stylings when I use media query in my CSS3

Tags: html, css

```css
/*------standard CSS file----------*/
.title{
   font-size:45px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:768px){

      .title{
          font-size:20px;
      }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title">MY Title</h1>
```

I'm using the normal title and give him styling size when the screen is normal size but when I give media query it applying the style in all cases size screen

Comment: It should work fine, Please make sure screen width is greater than `768px`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to confirm that your screen size that you’re testing on is bigger than what your media query is set to trigger at. If it’s less then the 768px you have set, then it will set whatever the media query is.

Comment: i tryed in all cases size screen and my width screen is 1200px but still the same